# How do I extract words in braces using regular expressions?

Tags: java, regex

I want to extract all *words* enclosed in curly braces, so I have an expressions like this

```
foo {bar} moo {mar}
```

The string to match may have any number of these words, but I'm starting to think I'm approaching this problem in the wrong way.

**My attempt**

And I've tried to extract the words braces into groups so I can use every single match. So, I made a regex:

```
String rx = ".*\\{({GROUP}\\w+)\\}.*";
```

Note: I'm using JRegex syntax so I need to escape some of the curlies.

**Result**

The result I get is a single (albeit correct) match `bar`, whilst I expect two matches `bar` and`mar`. What have I misunderstood, and how do I correct it? I probably need to use some other quantifier for the `.` part, but I hope you can help me with that too.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex `.*\{({GROUP}\w+)\}.*` doesn't work because it matches all your input string in one time :

- `.*` matches `foo`
- `\{({GROUP}\w+)\}` matches `{bar}`
- `.*` matches `moo {mar}`

You should use something like this :

```
List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();

Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\{([^}]*)\\}");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
while (regexMatcher.find()) 
{
  matchList.add(regexMatcher.group());
}
```

*Inner curly braces aren't handled by this regex*

Comment: "(?<=\\{)([^}]*)(?=\\})" regex should give you the words without the braces around them.

Answer (score 2):

A variant, using the reluctant modifier ".*?" in the regex expression. You can find additionnal information about the search strategy of a regex (greedy, reluctant, possessive) here : http://javascript.about.com/library/blre09.htm

```
List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();

Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\{(.*?)\\}");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    matchList.add(regexMatcher.group());
}
```

The syntax choice is yours. This regex will have the same comportement as @madgnome's one. Personnaly, I prefer using reluctant search rather than a character exclusion...